# Prestige Classes - Unusual Base Classes

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class, class

So, from what I can find, most prestige classes have requirements for the usual base classes. Sorcerer, Monk, Rogue, etc..

But what if your base class is something unusual, say a Beguiler? Are there any SRD rules that would allow someone of a level 5 Beguiler to take a Prestige Class that Requires another Level 5 Base class?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. An interesting question that definitely needs to be narrowed. As for why, consider this list of hundreds of [prestige classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_prestige_classes) and this list of 10s of [base classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_alternative_Dungeons_%26_Dragons_classes#3rd_and_3.5_editions). However, if you're interested in a specific question like *Are there any beguiler-only prestige classes?* the site can answer a question like that. Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: I was going off of Chet’s compiled list of Prestige Classes, and they list the PreReq’s as Specific Classes. Now I see I only need Arcane Caster 5, which I have. Thank you!

Comment: Why bother putting this on hold when it was already answered?

Comment: If I may speculate: That a question's on hold isn't, like, punishment or anything but an indication that the question needs to be clarified, expanded, or contracted before it's a good fit for the site. As it stands, even though an answer's been provided, the question itself *still* needs narrowing to be a question that fits well within the site's guidelines. That said, you don't *have* to fix the question if you've received an answer you're happy with.

Answer (score 8):

#### Actually, prestige classes *don't* have fixed classes as prerequisites.

D&D 3rd edition intentionally designs prestige classes so that while they're generally geared toward a certain character class, they're not restricted to that class. This is why you get prerequisites like "Base attack bonus +5" rather than "Fighter level 5", so that for example a 7th level monk can also take this class.

The beguiler straight-up qualifies for any prestige class for which they meet the prerequisites. This includes things like being an arcane spellcaster, being able to cast spells of a given level, being able to cast any spells that are on the beguiler's spell list, and so on.

I'm unaware of any actual core prestige class which specifically requires you to be of a certain character class. Any homebrew classes which do this are poorly designed, and you should feel free to fix them to the more inclusive standards.

Now, where you may encounter some difficulty is with something very different like the binder (from *Tome of Magic*). Classes like these straight-up don't have spell slots, arcane casting, the ability to prepare spells, or the ability to cast spells, and unfortunately won't qualify for many prestige classes intended for spellcasters.

In that case, your DM can make allowances, but strictly speaking there's no rule in the core rulebooks or SRD which would allow you to take levels in a prestige class for which you do not meet the prerequisites.